# Solving ODE $\dot{x} = -e^{-t} f(x, t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods

For standard ODE,
$$
\dot{x} = f(x,t).
$$
[Runge Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) methods are well-designed solvers and its order conditions are well studied. If $f(x,t)$ is well-behaved, RK are good solvers.

Now consider if I have ODE

$$
\dot{x} = -e^{-t} f(x,t).
$$

Is this ODE studied before or are there any high order solvers designed for solving the ODE? I think a good solver should take care of the factor $-e^{-t}$.

Comment: You shouldn't mix the $\dot{x}$ notation and the $dt$ notation. Your first equation, for example, should read $$dx=f(x, t)dt.$$ The way you wrote, it translates to $$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x, t)dt, $$ which suggests $$dx=f(x, t)(dt)^2, $$ and the latter makes no sense.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks. I update the question

Comment: Let $\tilde{f}(x,t) := - e^{-t} f(x,t)$. If your solver can solve $\dot{x} = f(x,t)$, why can't it solve $\dot{x} = \tilde{f}(x,t)$?